# Executing code after MediaPlayer is done playing?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-handler, android-speech-api

I was wondering I'm working on an Android app where MediaPlayer/TextToSpeech is used to tell the user something and then a Speech Recognition object opens up after the MediaPlayer/TextToSpeech finishes and another is played after they answer the question with the recognition. Problem is I'm not 100% sure of a way, or good way, to delay the Speech Recognition from opening right after MediaPlayer is starts, or waiting till mediaplayer is done before speech recognition opens up. I see a few options based off my own knowledge/Google -

use the methods isPlaying(MediaPlayer)/isSpeaking(TextToSpeech) and putting them in some kind of loop to check until they aren't true anymore, then opening the speech recognition.

Call Thread.sleep(). The problem I see with this is I'm not sure exactly how long user is going to speak so it could still get interrupted unless I put it at a high time which just slows the app down.

I've research and played around with the Handler class a bit, but haven't fully comprehended how to do this...anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something when a `MediaPlayer` finishes, you can set a [OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) with [setOnCompletionListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)) to receive a callback when the media playback is complete.